# How can I set “Other Linker Flags” to include -ObjC with CMake?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cmake, linker

I am trying to generate an XCode project with CMake, but I can't define "Other linker flags" in project settings. I have tried using the following:

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-ObjC")
```

and

```
target_link_options(my_project_target PUBLIC "LINKER:-ObjC")
```

and

```
add_link_options("-ObjC")
```

unlike similar posts, I am not trying to link a framework or library, I want to specifically set the `-ObjC` linker flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try target_link_libraries

```
target_link_libraries("-ObjC")
```